# Why is this injection from $\mathbb{N^N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ wrong?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was looking to generate an injection from $\mathbb{N^N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and this is what i created:
$$
\begin{align*}
g: \mathbb{N^N} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}  \\
f \mapsto p_1^{f(0)}p_2^{f(1)}p_3^{f(2)} \dots
\end{align*}
$$
Where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.
It looks like it creates an injection due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but as it maps to only natural numbers, I can't see why its wrong, because clearly $|\mathbb{N^N|} > |\mathbb{N}|$?

Comment: If $f(n) > 0$ for all $n$, what natural number is $g(f)$?

Comment: The infinite product does not converge.

Comment: If the sequence is infinite, the result is not a not a natural number as it is infinitely large.

Comment: Oh, it should be infinity right? I completely missed that. Thank you!

Comment: It's an injection from all *finite* sequences but ... that's the rub... the cardinality of *finite* things are countable but the cardinality of *infinite* things are not. More or less-- that's an overgeneralization but it's mostly right.